# i want to sort my List view with price but my price object i get with My Web Service ? also this object value similar like "$49.55" same as "$39.55"

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview

Then how can i compare both value? 
Which Datatype is used for them? 
I get string type data. 
How to Parse the data for compare value?

This is my spinner click event. how can i sort upper value with my "JSON" Service Object.

```
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             final TextView selectedText = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
            if (selectedText != null) {
                selectedText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                if (id == 1) {
                    selectedText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    Collections.sort(mlistElectricity, new Comparator<RetailerPlanBean>(){
                        @Override
                        public int compare(RetailerPlanBean emp1, RetailerPlanBean emp2) {
                            return emp1.getmPRICE().compareToIgnoreCase(emp2.getmPRICE());
                        }
                    });
                    mRateLv = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.find_enery);
                    mRateLv.setAdapter(new FindRateAdapter(getActivity(), mlistElectricity));
                    mAllListCountTv.setText(""+mlistElectricity.size()+" LIST");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else if (id == 2){
                    selectedText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    Collections.sort(mlistElectricity, new Comparator<RetailerPlanBean>(){
                        @Override
                        public int compare(RetailerPlanBean emp1, RetailerPlanBean emp2) {
                            return emp2.getmPRICE().compareToIgnoreCase(emp1.getmPRICE());
                        }
                    });
                    mRateLv = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.find_enery);
                    mRateLv.setAdapter(new FindRateAdapter(getActivity(), mlistElectricity));
                    mAllListCountTv.setText(""+mlistElectricity.size()+" LIST");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else {
                    selectedText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: if you're getting it as a String, substring the dollar sign, convert the string to a float/double (parseFloat()/parseDouble()) and then compare values or manipulate the number as you please and then convert back to string (String.valueOf()) to display with the dollar sign concatenated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bradley mentioned you have to extract the price from String

```
Collections.sort(mlistElectricity, new Comparator<RetailerPlanBean>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(RetailerPlanBean emp1, RetailerPlanBean emp2) {

        double emp2Price = Double.parseDouble(emp2.getmPRICE().replace("$",");
        double emp1Price = Double.parseDouble(emp1.getmPRICE().replace("$",");

        if (emp2Price == emp1Price )
            return 0;
        else if (emp1Price > emp2Price )
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
});
```

Above will work only for '$'

And you can use subString method as well and remove first character.

Using subString method

```
double emp2Price = Double.parseDouble(emp2.getmPRICE().substring(1, emp2.getmPRICE().length());
double emp1Price = Double.parseDouble(emp1.getmPRICE().substring(1, emp1.getmPRICE().length());
```

Comment: but in my service doller also canadian dollar and many alphabetic come with object  and how to remove first character .

Comment: check my updated answer. However you will find easily these answer in old SO question. Kindly do a R&D before asking.

Comment: also buddy i cant use compareToIgnoreCase in double datatype.

Comment: sorry @kunu . i can't see the notification.

Comment: yeah as it double value you can use manual compare inside your method. check my updated answer